# ZlibStream uncompressed size differs from original uncompressed size

Tags: c#, .net, zlib

I am using .NET 6's `ZlibStream` to compress Data.
I noticed that when I compress the data and immediately decompress it, the sizes of the original data and the uncompressed data are different.

I use the following functions to compress and decompress:

```cs
public static class ZLib
{

    public static byte[] CompressData(Stream inStream, CompressionLevel level = CompressionLevel.Optimal)
    {
        using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var compressStream = new ZLibStream(outStream, level, false) )
            {
                inStream.CopyTo(compressStream);
                return outStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    public static byte[] DecompressData(Stream inStream)
    {
        using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var decompressStream = new ZLibStream(inStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                decompressStream.CopyTo(outStream);
            }
            return outStream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static byte[] CompressData(byte[] inData, CompressionLevel compressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Optimal)
    {
        using (var inStream = new MemoryStream(inData, false))
            return CompressData(inStream, compressionLevel);
    }

    public static byte[] DecompressData(byte[] inData)
    {
        using (var inStream = new MemoryStream(inData, false))
            return DecompressData(inStream);
    }
}
```

And the usage is as follows:

```cs
private byte[] _texture32Data = ...;
//...//
byte[] texture32Compressed = ZLib.CompressData(_texture32Data, compressionLevel);
var texture32UncompressedSize = _texture32Data.Length;
var uncompressed = ZLib.DecompressData(texture32Compressed);
Debug.Assert(uncompressed.Length == texture32UncompressedSize); // Assert fires here
```

> uncompressed.Length = 10153463
> texture32UncompressedSize = 10223616

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:

Context:

I am currently refactoring out our MiniZ dependency. When I use MiniZ, the sizes are correct.

Comment: Have you done a comparison of the files to see what's different?

Comment: Flush the streams (after `CopyTo()` e.g., `inStream.CopyTo(compressStream); compressStream.Flush();`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from @Jimi helped.
The issue seems to be that `ZlibStream` is not properly flushed when **compressing**.

The necessary change was to put `outStream.ToArray()` outside of the `using` of the `ZlibStream` like so (`Flush()` is called when disposing):

```cs
        public static byte[] CompressData(Stream inStream, CompressionLevel level = CompressionLevel.Optimal)
        {
            using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var compressStream = new ZLibStream(outStream, level, false) )
                {
                    inStream.CopyTo(compressStream);
                }
                return outStream.ToArray();

            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe keep the result as a stream also, then you don't need to `ToArray` it.